# Difference between dates by awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have the below file:

```
1,2,3,4,5,2015-10-13,7,8,2037-01-15
1,2,3,4,5,2015-09-05,7,8,2040-01-15
1,2,3,4,5,2015-09-15,7,8,2016-06-15
1,2,3,4,5,2015-10-13,7,8,2015-07-08
1,2,3,4,5,2015-11-02,7,8,2015-08-02
```

Using `awk`, How can I check the number of days between two dates ($6 and $9)?

For the last record, the result should be `90`

is it doable? 
Thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question I assume you want to count all months as 30 days. In this case you don't need to use external tool (like `date`), just calculate number of days by yourself:

```
awk -F'[,-]' '{print 360*($6-$11)+30*($7-$12)+($8-$13)}' file

-7652
-8770
-270
95
90
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming gnu awk is ok here....

Here's one way, it gives the number of days difference.  But that isn't strictly what you want (2015-11-02 thru 2015-08-02 is 92 days and you want a result of 90).

```
$ awk -F, '{ gsub(/-/," ",$0); print (mktime($6 " 00 00 00")-mktime($9 " 00 00 00"))/86400 }' file.txt
-7765.04
-8898.04
-274
97
92.0417
$
```